# Python error when using r.reclass on raster with no CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, grass-gis, reclassify

I have a set of GRID data (directory of .adf files) that I'm trying to reclassify in QGIS.

I'm using the GRASS r.reclass function to try to reclassify the layers, but GRASS keeps failing and throwing a python error. When looking through the log, it seems to be an issue with the projection. The data I have "reports no coordinate system" and thus defaults to WGS-84 when imported to QGIS. Looking through the log, the first error it gives is this:

```
GRASS_INFO_WARNING(15749,1): Over-riding projection check
GRASS_INFO_END(15749,1)

GRASS_INFO_ERROR(15749,2): Illegal latitude for North 
GRASS_INFO_END(15749,1)

GRASS_INFO_ERROR(15750,1): Invalid input 
GRASS_INFO_END(15750,1)
```

I recognize that this is just a partial section of code and may not be that helpful, but any ideas on why GRASS/QGIS is throwing this error? I was able to successfully reproject other layers (with CRSs), so I don't think it's a compatibility issue between GRASS/QGIS. I also tried converting the data directory of .adf files to a .tif with GDAL thinking that might help, but no luck.

If the full log is helpful, I can update this post with that.

Comment: In what coordinate system / projection is your GRID data then? Did you try to assign the right one before doing r.reclass?

Comment: I'm not sure -- it doesn't report one. However I put it into a meters-based coordinate system and that seemed to do the trick. It looks like I was assigning the wrong one.

Comment: Maybe there is a metadata file that goes along with them, i.e. like a .prj for shapefiles? Or has the data creator something to say about the CRS?